# Add HTML support to taglist in vim (file has PHP and HTML code)

Tags: php, html, vim, exuberant-ctags, taglist

I have a file, which has PHP and HTML mixed code. By default, Vim recognized this extension as `php`. File extension is phtml.

I wonder if I can add support to taglist (which is a Vim plugin) for that kind of file. I have exuberant-ctags installed too.

I searched in Google, found [this](http://blog.g-design.net/post/4603526300/add-html-support-to-taglist-in-vim) but it did not work. It seems the code is wrong; instead of seeing the tags on the left, I can see the name of the file.

Comment: is the filetype `php` or `html`?

Comment: @JoseElera: Thanks for your comment, José. Filetype is phtml. It seems  it is a combination between php and html.

Answer (score 1):

The taglist plugin is rather old, and has not been kept up to date.  I suggest you switch to Tagbar, which was written as an update and replacement:  http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465 or http://majutsushi.github.io/tagbar/.

With no attention to configuration, I created a simple file, foo.phtml:

```
<?php

function Foo() {
  return 'bar';
}
?>
  <p>Foo says <?php echo Foo(); ?>.</p>
```

After :TagbarOpen, I see the function I have defined:

```
" Press <F1> for help

▼ functions
    Foo
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, benjifisher. Do you know how I can make Tagbar show me the structure of HTML (apart from php functions) in case PHP and HTML code are mixed into one file?

Comment: I think that both Taglist and Tagbar rely on the tags generated by ctags.  Look at the tags file you get, and check the options for ctags.  See `:help tagbar-extend`:  if you can figure out which options to pass to ctags, then this explains how to configure Tagbar to do that.